Canonical embeddings in the surreal numbers
Which embeddings into surreal numbers are considered more canonical? I mean, surreal numbers are characterised by lots of automorpisms, so there is some freedom in choosing embedding of other sets and classes into surreals.
Yet, I possibly would not be wrong if I say that in canonical embedding of Hardy fields and (generalized) power series into surreals, $\omega$ is usually taken to be equivalent to the germ of $f(x)=x$. And when the surreal numbers are defined with derivation, it is taken to coincide with the derivative of the germs, that is, $\partial \omega=1$.
Now, this is what interests me. I want to embeed numerosities into surreals. Since numerosities follow the Euclid's principle (the whole is bigger than the part), they are totally ordered.
So, we have the numerosity of $[0,1)$ and numerosity of $[0,\pi)$, the both being of cardinality of continuum. The later is the greater than the former. The both have finite part (Euler's characteristic) zero (that's why we have to include only one boundary in the both). They are purely-infinite (belong to $\mathbb J$ in the surreal terminology).
The question is: to what surreal number each of them canonically corresponds? On the surface it seems that $[0,1)$ is simpler, so it must correspond to $\omega_1$. But from Fourier and Laplace transforms it follows that $[0,\pi)$ has simpler expression via $\omega$.
Below is the analytic overview for this.
First of all, we construct the "root-counting function" $\tilde{\delta}$, a surreal-valued function with the property $\int_S \tilde{\delta}(f(x)) dx$ is equal to the number of roots of the function $f$ on $S$. For finite number of roots it is equal to $\int_S\delta(f(x))|f'(x)|dx$ where $\delta$ is the conventional delta distribution.
Via Fourier and Laplace transforms, we can see that $\tilde{\delta}(x)$ can be expressed as a piecewise function with surreal domain, namely that $\tilde{\delta}(0)=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\infty dx=\omega/\pi$ and otherwise it is $0$.
We generalize this and postulate that $\tilde{\delta}$ can give the numerosity of the roots in the infinite case as well. Thus, $\int_S \tilde{\delta}(0)dx$ gives the whole numerosity of $S$. And this is equal to $\frac1\pi\int_S \omega dx$. The coefficient $\frac1\pi$ goes away only if we take an interval of length $\pi$: $S=[0,\pi)$.
So, what is the natural practice in constructing canonical embeddings? Should we choose the one which makes the coefficients to vanish?
